# Using echo or return in the_content filter

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie to Wordpress plugin development and I'm stuck just at the beginning.
I tried to develop a very simple plugin that add a link to each post. This is the code I tried as a first attempt:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_funct');

function my_funct($content) {
   return $content . '<a href="www.mysite.com">Link</a>';
}
```

but the result was simply appending the text 'Link' to the post, without any hyperlink.

Then I found that the following solution works:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_funct');

function my_funct($content) {
   echo $content . '<a href="www.mysite.com">Link</a>';
}
```

What's the reason why does not the first solution work?

Answer (score 0):

`the_content()` requires a simple `$content` to be returned...otherwise it will strip tags. If you want to `return` the content, you should be able to to so via:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_funct');

function my_funct($content) {
    $content .= '<a href="www.mysite.com">Link</a>';
    return $content;
}
```

See why this is so [in the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3b6c9519a8f83a3fd834bc047899b49547e9d592/wp-includes/post-template.php#L226).

Comment: This does not work either. Nothing is appended to the content of the post. Is it possible it is due to other filters already present in the theme I'm using?

Comment: Yes, highly possible. You could try adding a `$priority` as the third parameter of [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)...something like `add_filter('the_content', 'my_funct', 99);`...but the needed priority will depend on the priority of other functions hooking into `the_content`.

Comment: Nothing. Even adding a priority the 'return' based variation does not work